# JPype and JayDeBeAPI returns jpype._jclass.java.lang.Long

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-spark, jpype, jaydebeapi

I'm using [JayDeBeAPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) in PySpark (the [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) Python API), and here's the beginning of my code (note, I'm actually running all this through an interactive shell with PySpark).

```
import jaydebeapi
import jpype

conn = jaydebeapi.connect('org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver',
                  ['jdbc:phoenix:hostname', '', ''])
```

I am querying [Apache Phoenix](http://phoenix.apache.org/), which is an SQL "front-end" for Apache HBase.

Here's my Python code for the SQL query:

```
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('select "username",count("username") from "random_data" GROUP BY "username"')
curs.fetchall()
```

The output I'm getting is like this for all the rows:

```
(u'Username', <jpype._jclass.java.lang.Long object at 0x25d1e10>)
```

How can I fix it so that it actually shows the value of that returned column (the `count` column)?

From the [Apache Phoenix datatypes page](http://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html), the datatype of the `count` column is BIGINT, which is mapped to `java.lang.Long`, but for some reason `jpype` is not displaying the result.

I got JayDeBeAPI 0.1.4 and JPype 0.5.4.2 by `python setup.py install` when I downloaded them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The object returned by JPype is a Python version of Java's `java.lang.Long` class.  To get the value out of it, use the `value` attribute:

```
>>> n = java.lang.Long(44)
>>> n
<jpype._jclass.java.lang.Long object at 0x2377390>
>>> n.value
44L
```

JayDeBeApi contains a dict (`_DEFAULT_CONVERTERS`) that maps types it recognises to functions that convert the Java values to Python values.  This dict can be found at the bottom of [`__init__.py` in the JayDeBeApi source code](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/blob/master/jaydebeapi/__init__.py).  `BIGINT` is not included in this dict, so objects of that database type don't get mapped out of Java objects into Python values.

It's fairly easy to modify JayDeBeApi to add support for `BIGINT`s.  Edit the `__init__.py` file that contains most of the JayDeBeApi code and add the line

```
    'BIGINT': _java_to_py('longValue'),
```

to the `_DEFAULT_CONVERTERS` dict.

Comment: Thanks, I've added `BIGINT` to the dict. Is there a way to get rid of the tailing L without resorting to parsing?

Comment: @AlaaAli: The `L` at the end is just how Python 2 displays `long`s.  `n.value` is a Python `long` with value 44, not a string `'44L'`.

Comment: I've added [an issue to the jaydebeapi github project](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/issues/3)

Comment: It should be fixed in https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/tree/feature/improve-types-support. Appreciating any feedback.

Comment: Just an FYI -- This comment helped me bugfix a similar issue I ran into with migrating a legacy python program that used jaydebapi==0.2.0, JPype==0.6.3 and python 2.7.13, connecting to amazon redshift database.  Error thrown was [UserWarning: No type mapping for JDBC type 'BIT'].  Bugfix was to add the following lines of code: ```from jaydebeapi import _DEFAULT_CONVERTERS, _java_to_py        _DEFAULT_CONVERTERS.update({'BIT':_java_to_py('booleanValue')})
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Luke's answer: in case modifying the source is not practical, you can add converters at runtime.

```
import jaydebeapi
from jaydebeapi import _DEFAULT_CONVERTERS, _java_to_py
_DEFAULT_CONVERTERS.update({'BIGINT': _java_to_py('longValue')})
```

This fixed the issues I was having using jabdebeapi with Vertica.

Comment: This is a good fix, but in version `1.1.1` the line 
`
from jaydebeapi.dbapi2 import _DEFAULT_CONVERTERS, _java_to_py
`
should be changed to 
`
from jaydebeapi import _DEFAULT_CONVERTERS, _java_to_py
`

Answer (score 0):

The JayDeBeApi author adds that this method may need altering for very large integers, via the Java BigInteger's toString() method and then Python's int() function: https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/issues/6